# How to recursively do commands based on if a file exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to check if a file `new.htaccess` exists in multiple directories (recursive) and execute:

```
rm .htaccess
rename new.htaccess .htaccess
rm .htpasswd
```

I think a for loop might work but I am not sure of the syntax (I am a noob at for loops).

I think it should look something like this but as I said I am a noob and am not getting it to work right:

```
for -r new.htaccess in * do {
rm .htaccess
rename new.htaccess .htaccess
rm .htpasswd }
```

I am using Red hat linux with BASH v3.2.25 on a Godaddy 4GH shared hosting.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the starting directory, run:

```
find . -name "new.htaccess" -exec sh -c '
    f="{}"
    dir_f=$(dirname "$f")
    new_f="$dir_f/.htaccess"
    mv -f "$f" "$new_f"
    rm -f "$dir_f/.htpasswd"
' \;
```

Explanation:

1. `find . -name "new.htaccess"` finds recursively all "new.htaccess" files
2. For each file `f` (i.e. `./sub/dir/new.htaccess`), compute `dir_f` (i.e. `./sub/dir`)
3. Compute the path of the new file `new_f` (i.e. `./sub/dir/.htaccess`)
4. Move `f` over `new_f` (`-f` means "overwrite if necessary").
5. Delete `.htpasswd` in the same folder (`-f` means "don't complain if there is no .htpasswd")

Comment: @ElliotLabs notice that I changed it a bit now.

Comment: @wil93 You need to update **4.** to include `-f` to be correct, otherwise **NO** (overwriting if necessary) will take place. Try: `mv -f $f $new_f`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You're right, though just `mv` works fine on my system (it overrides if necessary). Could you try issuing `which mv` to see if "your" `mv` is actually an alias to `mv -n` or `mv -i`?

Comment: This is not the correct way to iterate over a list of file names; see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for why, and how you can do it correctly.

Comment: @chepner You're right, thanks. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: @wil93 I check both openSuSE and Archlinux and it is `/usr/bin/mv` in both cases with no `alias` involved.  Check `man mv` and `-f do not prompt before overwriting`. (systems that assign non-standard aliases to commands are asking for trouble) It took hours on the openSuSE install to get rid of that junk. Archlinux is just pure Linux, no cleanup needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's weird though. I also use Archlinux, my `mv` is from `coreutils 8.23-1` (and not aliased to `mv -f`) but overwrites without asking.

Comment: You are correct! That didn't/shouldn't work that way. `echo "a" > stuff` `echo "b" > newstuff` `cat stuff` `b`. I'll check the Arch list. There is nothing in the coreutils package that seems to change the default... Strange...

Comment: @wil93 I don't know when it changed, but `info mv` now reads `If a destination file exists but is normally **unwritable**, ... the file is skipped`. So it looks like `-f` is not required if the user has write permission for the destination file. Live and learn...

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, and here's another simple one:

```
find . -name new.htaccess -execdir sh -c '
    mv new.htaccess .htaccess
    rm .htpasswd
  ' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name new.htaccess -print | while read path; do (
    cd ${path%/*}
    mv new.htaccess .htaccess
    rm .htpasswd
    )
done
```

Here's the explanation from the `bash` manual on the `${path%/*}`:

> `${parameter%word}`
>
> `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The  word  is  expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of
>                 the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with  the  shortest
>                 matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the
>                 pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant  list.   If
>                 parameter  is  an  array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
>                 array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

So it gets the directory of the `.htaccess` file by removing the end part of the filename that matches `/*`.